# If segue was performed with identifier "segueHappened" run this function else run this function? is this possible?

Tags: ios, function, if-statement, swift, segue

```
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("segueHappened")! as Bool == true {
        selectedFromFavouritesQuote()
    } else {
        showFunFact()
    }
```

Any ideas on how to get my selectedFromFavouritesQuote()to run if a segue was performed else run my showFunFact() function.

so......if a certain segue happened say with a segue identifier "segueHappened". run this function selectedFromFavouritesQuote() else run this function showFunFact(). Can this be done?

Just to make it clear:

if a segue happened from Viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B, run selectedFromFavouritesQuote() function in viewcontroller B

if no segue happened from Viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B then run showFunFact() function in viewcontroller B

Comment: Your question is unclear. In which function have you placed this code. Do you want to do something different before the segue is performed? After? Do you want a different segue?

Comment: sorry for being unclear i'll edit the question. I meant to say if a certain segue happened. run this function selectedFromFavouritesQuote() else run this function showFunFact()

Comment: I still don't understand if you want to run the function in the source or destination view controller? I assume the destination?

Comment: if a segue happened from Viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B, run selectedFromFavouritesQuote() function in viewcontroller B

if no segue happened from Viewcontroller A to viewcontroller B then run showFunFact() function in viewcontroller B

Comment: You could pass data through the segue (with a property of the next ViewController), setting the value to isSeguedFromVCA, or isSeguedFromVCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your functions do and if they work or not, but as far saving a bool to NSUserDefaults, you should save it as a boolean and retrieve it as a boolean like so:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "segueHappened")

if defaults.boolForKey("someBool") {
    println("true")
} else {
    println("false")
    // Perform segue and set segue happened so next time it will evaluate as true
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "segueHappened")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. was wondering forages how to use userdeafualts will all types of data!

Answer (score 1):

In view controller A -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueToVCBId") {

       let vcb = segue.destinationViewController as ViewControllerB
       vcb.fromVCA=true
    }
}
```

In VCB -

```
var fromVCA=false

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if (self.fromVCA) {
        self.selectedFromFavouritesQuote()
    }
    else {
        self.showFunFact()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
        var segueHappened: Bool = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("segueHappened"))

        if segueHappened == true {
                self.selectedFromFavouritesQuote()
            } else {
                self.showFunFact()
            }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "segueHappened") // we are saving a variable called myName and we are giving it the value of "Bob"
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Thanks @Bluehound this is what I ended up with and it works!